# iphone UIKeyboard landscape

Tags: iphone, landscape, uikeyboard

How do I ask for a UIKeyboard to appear from the bottom of the iPhone screen (side, ie. left or right in portrait) when in landscape mode while editing a UITextfield?

Put more simply, I need a landscape UIKeyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

Comment: That's promising. Trying this again now that you say and it works. I must have uncommented and returned YES in the wrong UIViewController (that or not return YES often enough, I forget). I need a method like - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration to change the view before rotation. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can. I would guess that you would be messing with the `inputView` of your `firstResponder`, either by subclassing the inputView or overriding some property of the `firstResponder`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think Jumhyn's is the way to go.